# How place getter/setter methods at the bottom of a class definition in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I use the Generate function in the context menu to create my getter and setter methods. But there seems no way to tell Intellij to place the generated methods after the last method in the file ie at the bottom of the class definition. This is possible in Eclipse. Anybody know how to do it automatically in Intellij?

Comment: I know this will be out of topic but why do you want to place accessors at the bottom?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all a little hint. IntelliJ is designed to use without a mouse, so I prefer using the keyboard-shortcut Alt + Insert for code generating.

I don't know any possibility to generally define the place for inserting generated code. I recommend to place the cursor there, where you want to insert generated code and then generate it.

Comment: Good hint. This answer only makes sense if avoiding the mouse which is what I will do now in future!

Comment: very good idea, but if you use "rearrange code: option in  "reformat file" dialog (ctrl+alt+shift+l) ide will change setter and getter location in code.better idea maybe is using arrangement tab in code style - java in ide settings.

Comment: 1. What shortcut would it be on mac?
2. I can't place the cursor anymore when the getter-setter-popup is displayed.

Comment: 1. It depends on the keymap. By default it's Command + N. 2. You have to place the cursor there where you want to insert the getter and setter before pressing the shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to generate getters and setters via Generate menu, the only way is to place cursor at the bottom of your class (or wherever you want them to be)

But if your field is not used yet, there is another option: navigate to the field you need getter/setter for, press Alt+Enter (it calls intentions dialog) and choose "generate getter and setter" option. Then getter and setter will be generated at the bottom of the class (but not below inner classes if any).

Comment: Easiest solution! How do I place a cursor somewhere with a popup window open, anyway?

Comment: @vollukas you don't. Place cursor before calling the popup.

Answer (score 2):

```
settings > code style > java > arrangement
```

lets you customize the auto formatting options

Comment: I've just tried to create an arrangement matching rule for get methods. It does not seem to affect the position of generated accessors.

Comment: Ah! It only works when you place the cursor out of the class for which you want to generate accessor methods. Otherwise methods still placed at the cursor location.